# Using Active Directory & Exchange as a newsletter system with over 60,000 objects to sync daily

Tags: powershell, active-directory, newsletter, exchange-server-2010, phplist

I am handling a case where all outgoing e-mail needs to be filtered based on the user's subscriptions. There are 3 categories of newsletters, and a blacklist of people who have unsubscribed. The amount of blacklist is about 60,000 e-mail address.

We were first going to use a regular newsletter system (PHPList, Mailchimp, Industry Mailout, etc). However some people voice a concern if there's a possibility that some staff member could send outgoing e-mails accidentally to those who have unsubscribed. Then, a sysadmin said that he can set a transport rule that blocks the outgoing e-mail but the problem is there's a limitation of 8,192 characters in transport rules and the 60,000 email addresses won't fit in one transport rule.

So, the only option was to have a transport rule that checks if a user is in a member of a distribution list (the blacklist), and that the distribution list is synced everyday with a Powershell script. The member of the blacklist distribution list will be synced from another newsletter system every 24 hours.

`Set-TransportRule -Identity 'Blacklist' -Name 'Blacklist' -SubjectContainsWord 'Newsletter' -SentToMemberOf 'blacklist' -RejectMessageReasonText 'This person does not want to receive a newsletter' -RejectMessageEnhancedStatusCode '5.7.1'`

`import-csv blacklistunsubscribe.csv | foreach 
    {
    $contact = New-MailContact -Name $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -ExternalEmailAddress $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -OrganizationalUnit "CASL" 
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -id 'blacklist' -member $contact
    Set-MailContact -Identity $contact -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true 
    }`

**Questions**:

1) This will sync more than 60,000 objects (those who unsubscribed) in Active Directory every 24 hours. What's the impact of syncing this many object everyday in Active Directory?

2)  What do you think of this method? Is there a better way of doing this? What's your opinion on what should've been done?

Comment: Huh? Why would systems like phplist not work for you, when it works for so many others? I'm not familiar with it, but it has unsubscripe-functionality, and I bet the default settings ignores addresses that has unsubscribed from the system. If you have staff members who are able to bypass this without knowing it, then they probably shouldn't have access to the system at all. Why punish your AD domain with more work when it's your employees that needs the help?

Comment: This means that every email that leaves your organization will have to be checked against a list of 60,000 addresses before it can be sent. I'd expect you'll see a measurable increase in the CPU utilization on your transport servers and an increase in delivery latency times for all of your external emails.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, AD replicates group memberships individually (not as an aggregate), so you should be fine. What I see missing is how to remove people from the blacklist if they no longer belong there.